# Sharing object between child and fork process node js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on child process using fork. but got totally confused on few things

```
• will it (process)pass app object instance eg:- let app = express(); using IPC
```

I m trying to explain my senario, first I have server.js where I initialize (starting point) server and other file is my task.js from where I am doing heavy task like reading a big file data and sending data back to other server. For send I had require authorization from that server whose logic is present in main.js and  if any error occur I'm send email with few detail to client. Below provide code for email and authorization in main.js

```
 Let task = require('./task.js')
app.sendEmail = function (message, emailinfo, attachment){
 // my email logic
  }
app.auth= function(host,port)
 // Authorization logic
}
 New task(app).run()
```

In task.js (sample code)

```
Class Task { 
  constructor(app){
    this.app =app
  }
  run(){
    fs.readfile('myfile',function(err,data){

  if(err){ let msg =err; 
  let clientinf; clientinf.to = "client email"; 
  clientinf.cc = " other user in CC";
  this.app.sendEmail(msg, clientinf, attach);
  }else{
    let host='other server url';
    let port='port';
    this.app.auth(host,port);
 }
 })
  }
}
```

I want to run task.js  in one more thread . note cluster and worker(because I m using node 10.19 so not confident that worker works properly) I don't want to use . It is possible to use folk or spawn to share data between each other. If not how I can achieve my requirement using thread?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions. The first is using the `Worker` class from the `worker_threads` module but since you don't want to update the node version the second solution is using `fork` function from `child_process` module. They do pretty much the same thing to be honest I can't tell which is better but the `worker_threads` solution is more recent.

Solution 1:

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')
const task_script = path.join(__dirname, "./task.js")
 const obj = {data:"data"}
 const worker = new Worker(task_script, {
                workerData: JSON.stringify(obj)
              })
 worker.on("error", (err) => console.log(err))
 worker.on("exit", () => console.log("exit"))
 worker.on("message", (data) => {
                console.log(data)
                res.send(data)
  })
```

and you have to change the `task.js` code slightly.Here it is

```
const { parentPort, workerData, isMainThread } = require('worker_threads')

class Task { 
  constructor(app){
    this.app = app
  }
  run(){
if (!isMainThread) {
  console.log("workerData: ", workerData) //you have worker data here 
  fs.readfile('myfile',function(err,data){

  if(err){ let msg = err; 
  let clientinf; clientinf.to = "client email"; 
  clientinf.cc = " other user in CC";
  this.app.sendEmail(msg, clientinf, attach);
  parentPort.postMessage(msg) //use can send message to parent like this
  } else {
    let host='other server url';
    let port='port';
    this.app.auth(host,port);
     }
   })
  }
 }
}
```

And here is the **second** solution

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const forked = fork('task.js');

forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
});

forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

and the taks.js way of sending and recieving data with this method

```
class Task { 
  constructor(app){
    this.app = app
  }
  run(){
  //receive
  process.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
  });
  fs.readfile('myfile',function(err,data){

  if(err){ let msg = err; 
  let clientinf; clientinf.to = "client email"; 
  clientinf.cc = " other user in CC";
  this.app.sendEmail(msg, clientinf, attach);
   process.send(msg); //send method
  } else {
    let host='other server url';
    let port='port';
    this.app.auth(host,port);
     }
   })
  }
}
```

Comment: you solutin is good but my problem is how i can access main js object eg : app.auth

Comment: I haven't tested but I think with the first solution you can pass it as a stringified object to `workerData`

Comment: i know worker may work but not confident about second solution

Comment: it might work but I don't think you need the `Task`  to be a class just run your functions directly in the `on('message')` callback